# WNetAddConnection2 fails but net use succeeds

Tags: c#, network-programming

I am trying to Connect to a network resource using WNetAddConnection2 but its failing with error code ERROR_BAD_NET_NAME (Error Code 67).

But if use "net use" command with the same user name and password its succeeding though.

Any clues ?

```
public class NETRESOURCE
    {
        public int dwScope;
        public int dwType;
        public int dwDisplayType;
        public int dwUsage;
        public string LocalName;
        public string RemoteName;
        public string Comment;
        public string Provider;
    }
    [DllImport("mpr.dll")]
    public static extern int WNetAddConnection2(NETRESOURCE netResource, string password, string username, int flags);

    public class ServerConnect
    {
        private string serverName;
        private string userName;
        private string password;
        public int nResult;

        public ServerConnect()
        {
            serverName = "";
            userName = "";
            password = "";
            nResult = -1;
        }
        public void SetConnectionParam(string serName, string uName, string pwd)
        {
            serverName = serName;
            userName = uName;
            password = pwd;
        }

        public void Connect()
        {
            NETRESOURCE myResource = new NETRESOURCE();
            myResource.dwScope = 0;
            myResource.dwType = 0x00000001; //RESOURCETYPE_DISK
            myResource.dwDisplayType = 0;
            myResource.LocalName = "";
            myResource.RemoteName = serverName;
            myResource.dwUsage = 0;
            myResource.Comment = "";
            myResource.Provider = "";
            nResult = WNetAddConnection2(myResource, password, userName, 0);     


        }
    };

    public void ConnectToDataServer(string serverName)
    {
        ServerConnect oConnect = new ServerConnect();
        oConnect.SetConnectionParam(serverName, @"Domain\username", @"password");
        Thread connectionThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(oConnect.Connect));
        connectionThread.Start();
        while (!connectionThread.IsAlive) ;// Wait till thread starts and Alive
        int nCount = 0;
        while (connectionThread.IsAlive)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(500);
            nCount++;
            if (nCount == 10) // wait for 5 secs
            {
                //WriteLine(this, "Failed to Connect to to server " + serverName , LogStatus.Error);
                connectionThread.Abort();
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        }
        //WriteLine(this, oConnect.nResult.ToString(), LogStatus.Success);
    }
    public void ConnectToServer()
    {

        ConnectToDataServer(@"\\ServerName");
}
```

Comment: ERROR_BAD_NET_NAME has nothing to do with the username/password, but rather is thrown when the network name of the computer/server cannot be found.

Comment: I understand that. But net use seem to find that name and run successfully.

Comment: OK, sorry about that.  I wasn't sure because your question kind-of implied that you were focused on the username/password instead of the computer name.

Answer (score 0):

For one, we would need to see your code, as `WNetAddConnection2` is a Windows functions and thus P/Invoked, and P/Invoke operations are always very, very hairy.

On the note of assuming you've invoked correctly, there could be permissions in the way (this is especially true if you're running Windows 8). Try making sure to `Run as Administrator` when you luanch VS, as this will usually extend the same credentials to executing applications, whereas the console often has different permissions.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I edited my post with the code. I run WNetAddConnection2 in a thread to make sure I can abort it if it takes for ever. And I am running the this App with Admin privileges. And I issue "net use" on a Admin command window